# How to jump out to new page instead of displaying content in ng-view when using AngularJS routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

guys, I got a question about Routing function of AngularJS, that is, we know all contents will be displayed in ng-view if using Routing, but how could I jump out to a new page, e.g, when clicking "/logout" I want to quit to login.jsp?

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, I've got the problem solved. My angularJs is integrated with shiro, and I forgot to set logout page, after setting it, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to show this page even if you routes in angularjs don't know anything about that but you server part should be aware of this page and redirect properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to leave your app, add target="_self" and Angular will know to leave it alone.

```
<a href="/logout" target="_self">Logout</a>
```